# when not on mobile use the jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, desktop

I have a jquery function for a fixed sidebar. but i only want to use the scrolling function for desktop. so if it's opened on a mobile phone i want him to do nothing. when i'm on desktop i want him to print this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var offset = $("#sidebar").offset();
        var topPadding = 15;
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                },200);
            } else {
                $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: 0
                      },200);
            };
        });
    });

</script>
```

I tried to do it like this, but this didn't work. then it will never go with you when you scroll down the page.

```
    <script>
var isMobile = {
Android: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
},
BlackBerry: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
},
iOS: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
},
Opera: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
},
Windows: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
},
any: function() {
    return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
}
};

if(isMobile.any()){
document.write('')
} else {
 document.write('<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var offset = $("#sidebar").offset();
        var topPadding = 15;
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                },200);
            } else {
                $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: 0
                      },200);
            };
        });
    });

</script>')
}</script>
```

Comment: Go check modernizr. http://modernizr.com/

Comment: +1 for Modernizr @MelanciaUK

Comment: Rather than basing it on device type, why not use a media query to check the viewport size?